# Python: Is there a better way to construct a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

There are multiple dimensions and metrics that I want to pull from Google Analytics via their API, and this requires dimension:metric(s) pairing. Naturally, I thought dictionary might be a good option for this. To minimize typing, and increase readability, this is what I tried.

```
dim_dict = {
    0:'',
    1:'ga:searchUsed',
    2:'ga:searchKeyword',
    3:'ga:pageTitle',
    4:'ga:operatingSystem',
    5:'ga:goalPreviousStep3'
    }

metric_dict = {
    1:'ga:sessions',
    2:'ga:sessionDuration',
    3:'bounceRate',
    4:'pageviews',
    5:'ga:searchSessions',
    6:'ga:goalCompletionsAll'
    }

dim_metric_dict = {
    0:[1,2,3,4,5,6],
    1:[1,2,3,4,5,6],
    2:[1,2,3,4,5,6],
    3:[1,2,3,4,5,6],
    4:[1,2,3,4,5,6],
    5:[6]
    }

query_dict = {}
for dim_key in dim_dict.keys():
    met = []
    for metric_key in dim_metric_dict[dim_key]:
        met.append(metric_dict[metric_key])
    query_dict.update({dim_dict[dim_key]:met})
```

Then, I'm using the following code to make API requests:

```
def get_ga_kpi(start_date, end_date, dimensions='', sort='ga:pageviews'):
    service = build('analytics', 'v3', http=http)
    metrics = query_dict[dimensions]
    if sort not in metrics:
        sort = metrics[0]
    data_query = service.data().ga().get(**{
        'ids': 'ga:#######',
        'metrics': '%s' % (','.join(metrics)),
        'dimensions': '%s' % (dimensions),
        'start_date':'%s' % (start_date),
        'end_date':'%s' % (end_date),
        'sort': '-%s' % (sort)
        })
    return feed['rows']
```

The code works as intended, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to approach this problem. Thanks for any input!

Comment: from what i see, it's the best approach - otherwise you can try parsing a YAML with the specs

Comment: It may be a case you want to extract these out into data files - that's a lot of data to be embedded into the source.

Comment: @Lattyware, could you elaborate what you mean by "the source", and what would data files look like? I'm still learning the lingos :)

Comment: I think he just means "the source code." Namely, your main program versus a separate file to store string data in.

Comment: @user3499545: ah I see... maybe I don't understand this correctly, but do you mean that I would store the dictionaries in a separate .py file? or utilize something like .txt as dimension-metric pairing

Comment: You could do either.  You could make a .py file with a class that just stores a bunch of dictionaries and then import that or you could keep them in some sort of csv or other text file.

Comment: @user3499545: I just started learning more about classes in python (and python is my first programming language), and I'm having trouble visualizing what this class would look like... Could you edit your response to include this? This seems like the most appealing solution so far

Comment: I'll try to edit my answer later, but I actually misread your question.  There should be a more efficient way to do this than with the precursor dictionaries you're just using to iterate through. If someone submits a solution before I have a chance to edit, I'll just remove my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is much better, but you could use a dictionary comprehension and enumerate to avoid typing out all of the numbers.

For example, the dim_dict construction could become:

```
    dim_list = ['','ga:searchUsed','ga:searchKeyword','ga:pageTitle','ga:operatingSystem','ga:goalPreviousStep3']
    dim_dict = {key:value for (key,value) in enumerate(dim_list)}
```